# Múltiplas datas com insert TO_DATE no oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, data

recorri a perguntar pois não achei a solução nem no Stack overflow PT nem no EN, então caso alguém vote negativo ao menos me informe o link para consulta.

Preciso inserir duas datas na minha base de dados **ORACLE**, colunas INICIO e FIM.
Após preparar a query com o **PHP** ele insere a primeira data corretamente e por algum
motivo a segunda data é inserida sem o formato sendo que uso o mesmo tratamento.

```
$dtstart = '14-01-2022 12:39:00';
$dtend   = '14-01-2022 13:39:00';

$insert = "
INSERT INTO HORA (INICIO,FIM) VALUES (TO_DATE(:d,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss'),
TO_DATE(:c,'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss'))";

$statment = $conn->prepare($insert);
$statment->bindValue(':d', $dtstart);
$statment->bindValue(':c', $dtend);


if($statment->execute()){
  echo 'ok..';
}
```

Após a execução eu tenho isso na minha tabela:
**[INICIO:14/01/2022 12:39:00]--[FIM:14-JAN-22]**

Como tratei os 2 com TO_DATE na inserção, não entendo como a segunda data chegou sem formatação.

Comment: Por que em "dtstart" você usa bindValue(':d') e bindValue(':c') e no "dtend" só utiliza bindValue(':c') ?

Comment: Perdão, não me atentei a isso, eu fiz a correção no código acima, o bindValue(':c') recebe o dtend mesmo, eu havia alterado para tentar enviar o valor da mesma variável para o banco, mas não muda nada.

Comment: O meu problema era a coluna FIM do banco de dados, que ao invés de estar no formato DATE como a INICIO, estava varchar, eu fiz a alteração e isso resolveu o problema.

Comment: Um dos "problemas" do Oracle e esta conversão automática entre 'types' , muita vezes gera confusão.